# OL3 check if point is inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When I am adding a point to my web map I want to give it a letter that represents the area where the point is, so I need to know what area the point is in.
In OpenLayers 2 I did it like this:
`areas[i].geometry.containsPoint(point)`   ---> returns true if it does.

Is there anything like this in OL3?

I searched in the [OL3 API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/index.html) but didn't find it.

Comment: It would be reasonably straightforward to write, following the example from OL2. Point in polygon calcs are about 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `yourVectorLayer.getSource().getFeaturesAtCoordinate(point)`. The result is an array, if its length > 0 then the point is inside, otherwise it's not.

Comment: Does this really work? Which version of ol3 are you using? I think the getFeaturesCoordinate() method is knackered (ol3.11).

Answer (score 2):

These kind of operations aren't supported out of the box in ol3. (maybe in  the future).

But you can use a library like http://turfjs.org , in this case you'll need https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-within or https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-inside

You can use [ol.format.GeoJSON](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html?unstable=true) to  convert from a ol3-geometry and geojson for turf and back.

Comment: And,  [jsts](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts).

Comment: yes that is an other option, in that case you'll need ol.format.WKT for conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version as of writing is 3.16.0, has the API: `ol.extent.containsXY(extent, x, y)`

See more info in the [latest API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.extent.html?stableonly=true#.containsXY)