# Checking if point is inside irregular polygon?

Tags: javascript, polygon, point-in-polygon

I'm using Javascript (https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon) to test if a point is inside polygon, however I think it's adapted from https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

Following are the list of points,

```
let points = [
            [ 42.34624, -71.06024 ],
            [ 42.33558, -71.06616 ],
            [ 42.32632, -71.05835 ],
            [ 42.32987, -71.05428 ],
            [ 42.34732, -71.05432 ],
            [ 42.34618, -71.05973 ],
            [ 42.34624, -71.06024 ]
        ];
let testPoint = [
            [42.33288, -71.05804]

        ];`

let isInside = pp(testPoint, points);
expect(isInside).to.equal(true); // always fails
```

[image]

I'm not sure why it fails though. Is it because the algorithm doesn't cope with this "type" of polygon? Any hints please? Please point me to any  alternatives to this approach as well.

Comment: I am using Angular 2 and I also want to use point-in-polygon but somehow I am not begin able to use it because it does not have a typescript definition nor an Angular 2 module. Can you tell me how you can import the JavaScript to your Angular 2 project?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it.

Comment: why? is this one not good enough? :(

Comment: The problem is that you have put it as an answer, which it is not.

Comment: I know but i have no reputation to comment...

Comment: Yes, this issue comes up often and I appreciate that you are trying to help. Try editing a few questions or something similar. You need very little rep to comment. However, a question is not an answer, I'm afraid, and this will get closed very soon for that reason.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100858)

Answer (score 3):

1. If you are using Openlayers see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131280/ol3-check-if-point-is-inside-a-polygon).
2. If you are using leaflet see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890294/leaflet-how-to-check-point-lies-inside-outside-of-polygon-or-rectangle).
3. For pure javascript see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/js-check-if-point-inside-a-polygon) or for NPM resources [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/point-in-polygon) or [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robust-point-in-polygon)

There are other solutions beyond these but this should be enough to be getting on with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/js-check-if-point-inside-a-polygon - the project suggested in one of the answers there is the project I'm using. It says the test point isn't inside the polygon I'm testing against.

Comment: There are two solutions.  One is labelled as the solution which finally worked.  If you don't like that solution I suggest you look at one of the NPM resources and adapt the code there to your purposes.  However, without knowing how you implemented the solutino I can't say any more.

Comment: Thanks, I've not implemented my own algorithm. I've tried using existing libraries - `import pp from 'robust-point-in-polygon'`; and `import pp from 'point-in-polygon'` for doing the test, they both come up saying point is outside the polygon....

Comment: Figured out - apologies, it was the way I was feeding test points, it works now...! gosh, I should have had a coffee.